# Mysql dump for India Country latitude, longitude and AreaName

Tags: mysql, dump

Any body have the mysql dump that contains latitude, longitude and location name details
Please share with me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a free city-level database that covers India.  You can download one from here:

http://www.geobytes.com/FreeServices.htm

Look for the GeoWorldMap section and follow the instructions.